# Whats the best solution for mail, contact, calendar and task syncing?

Tags: 14.04, email, sync, calendar, imap

Im hoping someone can help. Im looking for a complete solution that would allow me to sync Outlook's Calendar, Contacts and Task manager with Ubuntu. Im running Ubuntu 14.04lts with Sendmail and Dovecot. Dovecot has been setup for IMAP and syncing of emails and folders works great.

I just need to sync the others now but can't find a working solution.
Many Thanks,

Comment: There is hardly any functional software supporting [CalDAV on 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/746627/caldav-client-for-ubuntu-14-04). The only thing that might work is [Lightning](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/lightning/).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want instructions for a server, but you don’t specify whether you just want instructions for setting up clients.

As you need to sync with Microsoft Outlook, you only have one option: the Exchange ActiveSync protocol. However, I’d recommend you also look into the open-source protocols CalDAV and CardDAV. They’re not supported in Outlook, but they’re supported by iOS, OS X, Android (requires free apps), GNOME, and KDE.

You can [setup Horde groupware](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-debian-horde-webmail) on your server. Horde can act as a calendar and contacts server and provides access to that data in a web interface, over the Exchange, CalDAV, and CardDAV protocols. Horde is mostly known for being a great webmail (IMAP front-end), but it also does a good job with contact and calendar management.

See the above link for complete instructions on setting up Horde for calendaring, contacts, and email for one–fifty users.