# Is there a simple task planner for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, thunderbird, evolution, calendar

I am using gnome-fallback on my desktop and looking for a simple calendar/planner app in which I can easily make notes of the appointments and afterwards it reminds me of my appointments using some sort of desktop notification. I know there is a `planner` software in the repository but it is overkill for my simple need. Also, I use `Thunderbird` as my email client so don't want to install `Evolution`. Appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 2):

**Orage** is a great option. It does what you need. Check it [here](http://www.kolumbus.fi/~w408237/orage/).

To install, just do as normal, e.g. using `sudo apt-get install orage`

Then, add the "Orage Panel Clock" item to the panel. If you double-click on the time, you will get the calendar. There you can add appointments, notes, events, etc, selecting the reminder properties for each.

If you do not want to integrate the calendar to the panel, you can find it in the app list. It is called Orage Calendar. In a terminal, it is `orage`. For preferences, run `orage -p`.

Comment: I've installed it but it does not provide anything interesting. It has only a `Global  time preferece'. Perhaps because I'm using gnome, not xfce?

Comment: It also has the calendar with planner. It is a single application. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are number of calendar applications available from the Software Centre that fit your needs, such as the [Evolution Calendar](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/gnome-shell/) or [Korganiser](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/korganizer/), but [none is functional at this stage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/746627/caldav-client-for-ubuntu-14-04) for different reasons.

Since you are already using Thunderbird, you might give a try to [Lightening](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/lightning/), the calendar extension for that E-Mail client. Among other things, it supports reminders and CalDAV.