# Can I force calendar sync?

Tags: cron, sync, calendar, caldav

I recently installed [California](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/California) and set up a bunch of calendars to sync with a Nextcloud instance. Hours and hours later I got a password prompt and they synced, which is cool, but then I shut down my computer and California didn't sync until I tried to open a `.ics` file, when it asked me to re-enter my password for each calendar.

I'd love to figure out how to put the syncs on a cron job or otherwise force them to happen at more frequent intervals.

I noticed that once sync happened, California and [Calendar](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Calendar) both show all my calendars, but neither one has any kind of "sync" option visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually have no idea how to solve this. What I did instead was set up `vdirsyncer` and `khal` which do actually work.

In 18.04 LTS this is resolved. Calendar has a "Synchronize" option in the hamburger menu.